# Replacing a show method for S4 class before the class is loaded

Tags: r, methods, r-s4

I have written a function which can replace the show method for the `DataFrame` class defined in the S4Vectors package. I am working a lot with these `DataFrame` objects and I don't like how the default show method works. For example, the show method ignores the `options("digits")` setting and always show a ridiculous number of digits. I want something more tibble style, more compact.

I use for this my [colorDF](https://january3.github.io/colorDF/) package, but it can also be done like this:

```
library(S4Vectors)
setMethod("show", "DataFrame", function(object) show(tibble::as_tibble(as.data.frame(object))))
DataFrame(mtcars)
```

That works well and I would like to set it automatically in all interactive sessions. However, if I put it in .Rprofile, before the S4Vectors package becomes explicitly or implicitly loaded / attached, I  get the error message

```
in method for ‘show’ with signature ‘"DataFrame"’: no definition for class “DataFrame”
```

However, I do not want to attach S4Vectors already in my .Rprofile.

Is there a way of setting up the method before the class is defined or otherwise solving this problem short of modifying the sources of S4Vectors?

For now, I load the S4Vectors namespace with `loadNamespace` in my .Rprofile before setting up the method – and this works as intended:

```
## in .Rprofile
loadNamespace("S4Vectors")
setMethod("show", "DataFrame", function(object) colorDF::print_colorDF(object))
```

Comment: You could try `trace`ing `loadNamespace` in your .Rprofil and add a line to it with an `if` condition that sets the method if S4Vectors is loaded.